# Eclipse Android - Database row ID should always "1" is it possible?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, rowid

I'm new in android and trying to make an app that you will input a message in an edittext and send it to another activity with a row ID = "1' in database, once it is sent

Another activity will receive this message and if the button named "Delete this message" is clicked the the messsage will be deleted in the database at the same time it's row ID

Once it is deleted, I can enter again a message with a row ID = "1" in database.

here is my code

```
 package com.example.pmfinal;

   import java.sql.SQLException;

   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


    public class DatabasePM {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "InfoDb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String KEY_ROWIDPM = "_id";
public static final String NOTIFPM = "notifpm";



private static final String TABLE_NOTIFPM = "notifprojman";

private static final String CREATE_NOTIFPM = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTIFPM + " ("       +
KEY_ROWIDPM + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
NOTIFPM + " TEXT NOT NULL); ";



private DbHelper ourHelper;
private Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context Context) {
        super(Context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTIFPM);
        ;


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NOTIFPM);


        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DatabasePM(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public DatabasePM open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}



public long createProject(String notifpm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NOTIFPM, notifpm);
    return ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_NOTIFPM, null, cv);
}

public String getNotif(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWIDPM, NOTIFPM};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NOTIFPM, columns, KEY_ROWIDPM + "=" + l , null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String notif = c.getString(1);
        return notif;
    }
    return null;
}

public void deleteNotifPM(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourDatabase.delete(TABLE_NOTIFPM, KEY_ROWIDPM + "=" + l , null);
}



}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I want to have just one row in my database.

Comment: If you just need to store at most one string, a sqlite database is an overkill. Consider shared preferences instead.

Comment: I agree with Shared Preferences option for this

Comment: Can I have example how to apply shared preferences with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Truncate` is `SQL` command which cleans the database with any old record references. SQLite database in Android does not have `Truncate` supported AFAIK. So what you need to do is `Drop` the table and re-create it. What it is doing now is, even you delete the row, the new row will be inserted at next index but not on the one you have deleted.
So `Drop` and re-create the table to achieve `rowID = 1` always.

Comment: No need to, plain `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` without autoincrement creates rowids as `MAX(id)+1` so if there's no data, the new insert gets id 1.

Comment: Ok, what about if deleted a record then what will be the new record PRIMARY KEY ?